# How to select all the rows in Pandas data set with NAN and then convert it into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Original Data][1] I have this data set of title of books read over the year. All I want to change from the original data is to add a new column named Date.

```
    Tittle         Page        Author    Rating
0   Monday, Mar. 1  NaN         NaN      NaN
1   Tittle 1        5.0         JHK      1.50
2   Tittle 2        13.0        ABB      0.03
3   Tittle 3        100.0       ACC      3.5
4   Tittle 4        9.0          NN      5.40
5   Tuesday, Jan. 2 NaN         NaN       NaN
6   Tittle 5        6.0         BBB      6.50
7   Tittle 7        14.0        CCC      10.00
8   Tittle 8        10.0        CNN      2.50
9   Wednesday, Dec.3 NaN        NaN      NaN
10  Tittle 10       5.0         CBS      1.00
11  Title 20        5.0         ABC      1.00
12  Title 21        25.0        JJJ      3.50
13  Title 22        1.0         NNN      7.50
14  Thursday, Mar.4 NaN         NaN      NaN
15  Title 25        100.0       VVV      9.00
16  Title 30        6.0         YYYY     9.00
17  Title 35        2.0         QQQ      9.00
```

I have tried using dropna() but in the end it just gets rid of the whole row.

```py
    dfs = pd.read_csv('Book2.csv')
    df = dfs.dropna()
    display(df)
        Tittle  Page    Author  Rating
1   Tittle 1    5.0     JHK     1.50
2   Tittle 2    13.0    ABB     0.03
4   Tittle 4    9.0     tvN     5.40
6   Tittle 5    6.0     BBB     6.50
7   Tittle 7    14.0    CCC     10.00
8   Tittle 8    10.0    CNN     2.50
10  Tittle 10   5.0     CBS     1.00
11  Title 20    5.0     ABC     1.00
12  Title 21    25.0    JJJ     3.50
13  Title 22    1.0     NNN     7.50
15  Title 25    100.0   VVV     9.00
16  Title 30    6.0     YYYY    9.00
17  Title 35    2.0     QQQ     9.00
```

I had tried to use pd.isna()  and make a new data-frame but its not turning out how I want it too look.

```py
    dfs = pd.read_csv('Book2.csv')
    df = dfs[dfs.isnull().any(axis=1)]
    display(df)

    Tittle  Page    Author  Rating
0   Monday, Mar. 1  NaN NaN NaN
5   Tuesday, Jan. 2 NaN NaN NaN
9   Wednesday, Dec. 3   NaN NaN NaN
14  Thursday, Mar. 4    NaN NaN NaN
```

In the end I just edited it manually in excel to make it look the way I want.
[I want it to look like this.][2]

````
    Tittle  Page    Author  Rating  Date
0   Tittle 1    5   JHK 1.50    Monday, Mar. 1
1   Tittle 2    13  ABB 0.03    Monday, Mar. 1
2   Tittle 3    100 ACC 4.50    Monday, Mar. 1
3   Tittle 4    9   tvN 5.40    Monday, Mar. 1
4   Tittle 5    6   BBB 6.50    Tuesday, Jan. 2
5   Tittle 7    14  CCC 10.00   Tuesday, Jan. 2
6   Tittle 8    10  CNN 2.50    Tuesday, Jan. 2
7   Tittle 10   5   CBS 1.00    Wednesday, Dec. 3
8   Title 20    5   ABC 1.00    Wednesday, Dec. 3
9   Title 21    25  JJJ 3.50    Wednesday, Dec. 3
10  Title 22    1   NNN 7.50    Wednesday, Dec. 3
11  Title 25    100 VVV 9.00    Thursday, Mar. 4
12  Title 30    6   YYYY    9.00    Thursday, Mar. 4
13  Title 35    2   QQQ 9.00    Thursday, Mar. 4

```




So I could sort or groupby the data by date later on if i want to see if there is a trend on the students reading habits in the future but for now I just want to add another date column and use the date that is all ready there in the data set if possible. I have to comb through a total of 181 pages of this and I am hoping pandas could help cut down the hours I will have to spend editing this manually in excel and using the copy and paste.

if you have any other recommendation in how to efficiently wrangle this data-set where the title will not mix in the same column and the NAN will be taken cared off. It will be greatly appreciated. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBihm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlJbE.png
````

Comment: Please post your data as text instead of image, also post the code you've tried and you'd like to have feedback on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the conditionally extracted data frame with three or more NA numbers with `fillna()`. Combine the resulting date sequence with the data whose NA is zero.

```
df1 = df.loc[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == 3].reindex(index=df.index)
df1.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df1 = pd.concat([df1[['Tittle']], df.loc[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == 0]], axis=1, join='inner')
df1.columns =['Date', 'Tittle', 'Page', 'Author', 'Rating']

df1
Date    Tittle  Page    Author  Rating
1   Monday, Mar. 1  Tittle 1    5.0     JHK     1.50
2   Monday, Mar. 1  Tittle 2    13.0    ABB     0.03
3   Monday, Mar. 1  Tittle 3    100.0   ACC     3.50
4   Monday, Mar. 1  Tittle 4    9.0     NN  5.40
6   Tuesday, Jan. 2     Tittle 5    6.0     BBB     6.50
7   Tuesday, Jan. 2     Tittle 7    14.0    CCC     10.00
8   Tuesday, Jan. 2     Tittle 8    10.0    CNN     2.50
10  Wednesday, Dec. 3   Tittle 10   5.0     CBS     1.00
11  Wednesday, Dec. 3   Title 20    5.0     ABC     1.00
12  Wednesday, Dec. 3   Title 21    25.0    JJJ     3.50
13  Wednesday, Dec. 3   Title 22    1.0     NNN     7.50
15  Thursday, Mar. 4    Title 25    100.0   VVV     9.00
16  Thursday, Mar. 4    Title 30    6.0     YYYY    9.00
17  Thursday, Mar. 4    Title 35    2.0     QQQ     9.00
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again for you help.